# Returning Promise of [Observable from Array]

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter, promise, reactive-programming

I designed this funciton that returns the tweets of an username as an array:

```
function getArrayOfTweetsFrom(username) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        T.get('statuses/user_timeline', {
            screen_name: username
        }, function (err, data, response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(Rx.Observable.from(data));
            }
        })
    })
}
```

it resolves to an Observable from this array called data (it's an iterable object since data[0] gives me the first tweet). Then, I did this:

```
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getArrayOfTweetsFrom('user')).subscribe((eachTweet) => {
    console.log(eachTweet)
});
```

but it logs an Observable object, I guess. It's iterable, when it shouldn't be because I'm outputing each tweet alone...

I'm getting a crazy iterable object which ends with

```
  _fn: undefined,
  _scheduler: CurrentThreadScheduler {} }
```

and those sorts of things that are from an Observable Object

UPDATE:

I forgot to `flatMap` because I was returning an observable, so here it is the updated code, but the same **problem persists**:

```
var cuteStream = Rx.Observable.just('cuteemergency').flatMap(
    (username) => {
        return Rx.Observable.
        fromPromise(getArrayOfTweetsFrom(username))
    }
).
subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: "Then, I did this:"... where s the `.then()` stage?

Comment: @Redu since I'm using fromPromise, I don't need a .then, don't I?